# problema al cargar 2 select con datos en Laravel 5.6.7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un problema al llenar dos select distintos dentro del mismo formulario  en laravel 5.6.7.

**vista: registro.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{ Form::label('empresa','Empresa:',['class' => 'control-label  ']) }                                    
      <select class="form-control">
          @foreach($empresas as $empresa)
             <option value="{{$empresa->id}}">{{$empresa->nombre}}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>                  
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
 {{ Form::label('modalidad','Modalidad:',['class' => 'control-label  ']) }}

  <select class="form-control">
      @foreach($modalidades as $modalidad)
         <option value="{{$modalidad->id}}"> 
             {{$modalidad->nombre_modalidad}}
         </option>
      @endforeach
 </select>
</div>
```

**ruta: web.php**

```
   Route::get('cursos/guardar', ['as' => 'registro',
                               'uses' => 'CursosController@selectEmpresas']);

   Route::get('cursos/guardar', ['as' => 'registro',
                               'uses' => 'CursosController@selectModalidades']);
```

**Controller: CursosController.php**

```
    public function selectEmpresas(Request $request)
    {
        $empresas = Empresa::all();
        return view('cursos.registro',compact('empresas'));//

    }

    public function selectModalidades()
    {
        $modalidades = Modalidad::all();
        return view('cursos.registro',compact('modalidades'));
    }
```

cuando cargo los dos select me sale el siguiente error:

> 'Undefined variable: empresas (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto-laravel\resources\views\cursos\registro.blade.php)',

Este error aparece cuando cargo los dos select al mismo tiempo , ya que probé al cargar solo el select de empresa y me trae los nombre de las empresas cargados en la tabla de la base de datos, posterior a esta prueba , comente el código de empresa y probé que me trajera solo un select en este caso modalidad y me trae perfectamente los datos de la tabla modalidades, el error solo sale cuando cargo los dos select juntos. (espero que se entienda ), les agradecería que me ayudaran ya que le he sacado humos al motor de google.

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado el problema , lo que hice fue unificar los dos llamados a las funciones  que se encontraban en el controlador , en una sola función y que me trajera dos arreglos (los datos de dos tablas independientes). La ruta quedo de esta manera:

```
Route::get('cursos/guardar', ['as' => 'registro',
                             'uses' => 'CursosController@LlenadoSelect']);
```

y el controlador quedo de esta manera:

```
 public function LlenadoSelect()
{
    $empresas = Empresa::all();
    $modalidades = Modalidad::all();
    return view('cursos.registro',compact('empresas','modalidades'));
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $empresa=empresa::pluck('nombre','id');
     $modalidad=tienda::pluck('nombre_modalidad','id');
     return view('controlador.create',compact('empresa','modalidad'));
```

asi le pasos los parametros que necesito al select.

Comment: que es emprea? y tienda? recuerda que los nombres de los modelos empiezan con mayúscula